# Do we need to clean-up in a multi-stage build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

It is a good idea to clean-up resources after installing in a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN \
  apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install gettext-base \
  && <commands>
  && apt-get clean \                       <--- CLEAN-UP
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*           <--- CLEAN-UP
CMD <command>
```

Is cleaning-up resources also necessary if the builder is part of a multi-stage build? Or will Docker erase all intermediate builds of a multi-stage build anyway? For example, is the following good enough?

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty as helper
RUN \
  apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install gettext-base \
  && <commands>

FROM ubuntu:trusty
COPY --from=helper <from> <to>
CMD <command>
```

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1065042/how-to-automatically-clean-up-remove-garbage-collect-helper-builder-images-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning resources from your "helper" is not mandatory, you will not have artifacts from previous stages in your final image.

You can see history and size of each step with `docker history [OPTIONS] IMAGE`

However for saving space on your machine it's recommended, each stages are saved as a docker image. You can see images whith `docker images` command.

Comment: So are you saying it's a good practice to manually clean up your builder/helper, and that they will not automatically get garbage collected?

Comment: It depends if you need spaces on your machine, because ach step of your dockerfile are saved as a docker image.

Comment: To me it’s an issue that I don’t know how many times this will get deployed, and that in this case it is dev, so it could be thousands... who knows? It would be incredibly tedious to clean all those up. I but I guess you’d set up a script just for that. So I’d need to be able to capture the list output of docker image ls into a script and recourse the thing...